# Sendkeys in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send keys using selenium and it does not want to send them on first try. Basically our application build on HTML5, Javascript, Angularjs. We have video player(Videogular from AngularJS) on first page. I can pause/play video by sending keys:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0050')).perform();
```

OR

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys(String.valueOf("p")).perform();
```

But when I'm trying to forward, rewind by sending keys the same way(f/r)

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys(String.valueOf("f")).perform();
```

Player does not react at all, sometimes I put in loop of 5 or 10 to see result
But if I'm using real keyboard it works on first try with no issues.
I did even this way:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys("f");
```

I clicked even on video player  before sending keys(which is no required in user story), still no luck

Spend all day to figuring out, still no luck. May be any one had similar issue and knows how to solve it?

Any help appreciated

[image]

Comment: html web elements for this player?

Comment: we are using Videogular from AnjularJS

Answer (score 0):

There's another sendKeys method in the *Actions* API which takes the targeted *WebElement*.

```
sendKeys(WebElement element, CharSequence... keysToSend)
```

I'd give that a shot.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);     
//FIXME:  Get correct lookup for the VideoPlayer element.   
WebElement videoPlayer = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));        
String play = "p";        
//Send "p" to the videoPlayer webElement
actions.sendKeys(videoPlayer, play).perform();
```

---

The method you're using

```
sendKeys(CharSequence... keysToSend)
```

sends the commands to the active element, which may not be the VideoPlayer you want to have receive the keys.

Comment: Thank you, for reply. But unfortunately the same result: works only for play/pause and not for rewind/forward  (((. I'm going insane because it does not make sense to me send one key and not others, but from keyboard works fine.. I was thinking to do through java script executor  `WebElement rewind = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
 myExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='r';", rewind);`  but did not work this way too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the keys to the body of the page, try sending them to the container with the keypress watcher added to it:

```
driver.findElement(RfBy.cssSelector(".video-container"))
      .sendKeys("f");
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it gives me exception: `WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, haven't run into that before myself. You can try sending the click event to the element before sending the keys, perhaps? There can also sometimes be issues depending on the web driver you are using (e.g. chrome, firefox, etc) and the selenium versions.

Comment: I tried it today as well, the same exception. I tried running on Chrome and Opera(our application does not support Firefox). Our application initially made for Amazon Fire TV, but we made local copy to do automation - that's why it supports only 2 browsers... I spend all day today at work figuring it out...even was trying to send sequence of letters "fffff" no luck(. I'm using latest one selenium 2.53

Comment: Just tried with different browsers, does not work. Probably will test it manually then. Thank you